# App store raw receipt in python

Tags: python, objective-c, app-store

I have what I think is a raw Apple app store receipt that I am trying to test with in Python.  The receipt looks something like this:

```
<30821e3b ... f1818d>
```

I think this is raw hex that needs to be converted to a UTF-8 string. I found Objective C code here http://goobbe.com/questions/2824360/apple-in-app-purchase-verify-receipt, that initializes a String with it that looks like this:

```
NSString *receiptStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:transaction.transactionReceipt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Any help writing a line of python that does the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a raw hex string you should be able to decode it like this:

```
hex_string = '30821...'
utf8_string = hex_string.decode('hex').encode('utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you feel you need to use the Cocoa classes from the ObjC code for some reason, you have the option to [install PyObjC](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html) (it's in pip), and make a very direct translation:

```
from AppKit import *
receiptStr = NSString.alloc().initWithData_encoding_(transaction.transactionReceipt, NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```